# How to replace plus sign by comma

Tags: replacement

I want to replace plus by comma and the order of numbers in the list should be in increasing order. Example:

```
a1 + a10 + a11 + a13 + a2 + a27 + a28
```

In this expression, I want to replace plus sign by comma and delete "a". To get a list of numbers and the order should be

```
{1,2,10,11,13,27,28}
```

I have tried this, but it's not convenient...

```
StringReplace["a1 + a 10 + a 11 + a 13 + a2 + a27 + a28" , "+ a" -> ","]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way:

```
expr = a1 + a10 + a11 + a13 + a2 + a27 + a28;

ToExpression@StringDrop[ToString[#], 1] & /@ List @@ expr

(* ==> {1, 10, 11, 13, 2, 27, 28} *)
```

You can then `Sort` them.

Answer (score 6):

Another option:

```
Block[
    {Plus = Function[Sort@ToExpression@StringReplace[ToString[{##}], LetterCharacter -> ""]]},
    a1 + a10 + a11 + a13 + a2 + a27 + a28
]
(* {1, 2, 10, 11, 13, 27, 28} *)
```

Works with other possibilities, such as `"b123"`, `"abc123"`, etc.

Answer (score 5):

```
expr = a1 + a10 + a11 + a13 + a2 + a27 + a28
```

Then:

```
expr /. Plus -> List // ToString /@ # & // StringReplace[#, "a" -> ""] & // ToExpression // Sort
```

Gives:

> {1, 2, 10, 11, 13, 27, 28}

Answer (score 5):

Yet another way:

```
Sort @ ToExpression @
  StringCases[ToString[a1 + a10 + a11 + a13 + a2 + a27 + a28], 
              DigitCharacter ..]
```

Comment: `NumberString` will do too. +1.

Comment: I just realized that my answer duplicates yours.  I hope my use of `DigitQ` and `FromDigits` is sufficient to justify the existence.  If you disagree I'll delete mine and add that variant to yours.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't have a problem with it.  Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 3):

The following employs only 3 functions.  (I assume the input is a string.)

```
Sort@ToExpression@StringSplit[t, {" + a", "a"}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another formulation:

```
expr = a1 + a10 + a11 + a13 + a2 + a27 + a28;

FromDigits /@ StringCases[ToString @ expr, __?DigitQ] // Sort
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 10, 11, 13, 27, 28}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by @R.M.'s answer, here is another way to temporarily define `Plus`:

```
Block[{Plus = Sort[FromDigits@StringDrop[SymbolName@#, 1] & /@ {##}] &}, expr]
```

> {1, 2, 10, 11, 13, 27, 28}

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought here because the question has already been answered well.
But If you had the **option of generating that equation** then your variables are named in an awkward way. It would be much easier if you had used subscripts.

$eqn= a_1+a_{10}+a_{11}+a_{13}+a_2+a_{27}+a_{28} $

Then you could have done something like this:

```
List @@ eqn /. Subscript[a, c_] -> c
```

Comment: There are other options such as down-values as well... however, using subscripts opens a whole new can of worms, especially with assigning definitions and clearing them :)