# Sequence of arbitrarily many variables separated by commas?

Tags: expression-manipulation

I am wondering if it is possible to produce an input such as

```
x[1],x[2],x[3],...,x[n]
```

for an arbitrary but fixed amount of `n` without having to type in every single term by hand. Note that the above is not supposed to be a list, but simply a sequence of variables and commas.

I thought that maybe a conversion of

```
x[1]+x[2]+x[3]+...+x[n]
```

to

```
x[1],x[2],x[3],...,x[n]
```

could do the trick. Something similar was asked in the question
[How to replace plus sign by comma](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40990/how-to-replace-plus-sign-by-comma)
but it does not provide the solution I am after, since it produces a list instead of sequence. Is there a convenient way to get such an input sequence in Mathematica? Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: What do you want to do with the sequence? `a,b` is not a valid Mathematica expression.  `{a,b}` or `f[a,b]` is.

Comment: I'd like to plug it into a differential operator `\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x[1], x[2],..., x[n]\)]`.

Comment: `Sequence @@ Table[x[i], {i, 1, n}]`?

Comment: `f[n_] := Sequence @@ x /@ Range[n]`?

Comment: Wow, amazing! And it does work with the differential operator too, thanks! If you guys put these as actual answers below I will thumb both up.

Comment: They're basically the same answer, but @MarcoB was first, so if he wants to post an answer, he can!

Comment: This can actually be done without `Sequence` too: `Fold[D, f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]`.

Comment: How about Array? `Array[x, n]` or `Sequence@@Array[x,n]` depending on what you are planning on doing with it.